# Parse command-line with sub-commands in C#

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

Is there a command-line parsing library for C# with good support for "sub-commands" in the style of git, svn etc.? For example, the "git" command has several sub-commands:

```
git add
git status
git diff
...
```

There are both global options that must precede the sub-command name, and options specific to the sub-command that must follow its name. For example, these do different things:

```
git -p add
git add -p
```

Different sub-commands might each have entirely different sets of options and arguments.

I've been using NDesk.Options, but up until now I haven't needed to implement sub-commands. I think it's flexible enough to build sub-commands on top of, but it's not entirely obvious how best to do this in a concise and elegant fashion. Is it possible to do this in NDesk.Options or is there a more suitable C# command-line parsing library?

Answer (score 2):

I'm partial to [my own option parsing library](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Nito.KitchenSink.OptionParsing), which I'm [blogging about currently](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/search/label/Option%20Parsing). I do plan to cover sub-commands, but it'll be a while before I get to it (it'll be one of the last posts).

Nito.KitchenSink.OptionParsing doesn't support sub-commands directly, but you can use the library to parse only parts of the command line, and handle the sub-commands yourself. The "global" and "sub-command-specific" option sets add an interesting twist, but it can be done like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Nito.KitchenSink.OptionParsing;

class Program
{
  private sealed class GlobalOptions : OptionArgumentsBase
  {
    // Use a better name than "POption". This is just an example.
    [Option('p', OptionArgument.None)]
    public bool POption { get; set; }

    // Override Validate to allow AdditionalArguments.
    public override void Validate()
    {
    }
  }

  private sealed class AddOptions : OptionArgumentsBase
  {
    [Option('p', OptionArgument.None)]
    public bool POption { get; set; }
  }

  static int Main()
  {
    try
    {
      // Parse the entire command line into a GlobalOptions object.
      var options = OptionParser.Parse<GlobalOptions>();

      // The first entry in AdditionalArguments is our sub-command.
      if (options.AdditionalArguments.Count == 0)
        throw new OptionParsingException("No sub-command specified.");
      object subcommandOptions = null;
      string subcommand = options.AdditionalArguments[0];
      switch (subcommand)
      {
        case "add":
        {
          // Parse the remaining arguments as command-specific options.
          subcommandOptions = OptionParser.Parse<AddOptions>(options.AdditionalArguments.Skip(1));
          break;
        }
        case "status": // TODO: Parse command-specific options for this, too.
          break;
        case "diff": // TODO: Parse command-specific options for this, too.
          break;
        default:
          throw new OptionParsingException("Unknown sub-command: " + subcommand);
      }


      // At this point, we have our global options, subcommand, and subcommand options.
      Console.WriteLine("Global -p option: " + options.POption);
      Console.WriteLine("Subcommand: " + subcommand);
      var addOptions = subcommandOptions as AddOptions;
      if (addOptions != null)
        Console.WriteLine("Add-specific -p option: " + addOptions.POption);

      return 0;
    }
    catch (OptionParsingException ex)
    {
      Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message);
      // TODO: write out usage information.
      return 2;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Console.Error.WriteLine(ex);
      return 1;
    }
  }
}
```

The sample program above produces the following output:

```
>CommandLineParsingTest.exe
No sub-command specified.

>CommandLineParsingTest.exe -p
No sub-command specified.

>CommandLineParsingTest.exe test
Unknown sub-command: test

>CommandLineParsingTest.exe add
Global -p option: False
Subcommand: add
Add-specific -p option: False

>CommandLineParsingTest.exe -p add
Global -p option: True
Subcommand: add
Add-specific -p option: False

>CommandLineParsingTest.exe add -p
Global -p option: False
Subcommand: add
Add-specific -p option: True

>CommandLineParsingTest.exe -p add -p
Global -p option: True
Subcommand: add
Add-specific -p option: True

>CommandLineParsingTest.exe status
Global -p option: False
Subcommand: status

>CommandLineParsingTest.exe -p status
Global -p option: True
Subcommand: status
```

Comment: Looks interesting. I'm not sure I understand how it handles the (admittedly confusing) case where there are identical global and subcommand options. Wouldn't "-p" be stripped out of options.AdditionalArguments and so subcommandOptions.POption could never be set?

Comment: The first time `OptionParser.Parse` is called, it is only considering the options defined by `GlobalOptions`. This will consume any arguments (including `-p`) before the sub-command. Since the sub-command isn't recognized as a valid global option, the rest of the command line is just placed in `GlobalOptions.AdditionalArguments` (all remaining options are considered positional arguments and they don't get parsed). After evaluating the sub-command (manually), I call `OptionParser.Parse` again, this time passing it the remaining command line, only considering the options defined in `AddOptions`.

Comment: Feel free to give it a test run - I copy/pasted the above out of a working Console application that had Nito.KitchenSink.OptionParsing installed via NuGet.

Comment: Ah, I see. I wasn't expecting that everything after the first positional argument would be treated as a positional argument. Now I see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Open Source project "Command Line" :

http://commandline.codeplex.com/

Comment: Does it come with any support for sub-commands? I don't see anything like that mentioned in the documentation. Is there any reason it would be easier to build sub-commands on top of Command Line than NDesk.Options?

Comment: http://commandline.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The-Option-Attribute&referringTitle=Documentation May give you the option. I see some option that contain parameter, you may just handle it from there.